# Cakephp CSRF protection

Tags: cakephp, csrf-protection

I am new to cakephp and now I am working on a new project with cakephp by studying. My current doing task is to do CSRF protection for overall project.I have read official cakephp 2 cookbook and I did as explained in that book. But, now I am facing

"The request has been black-holed.
Error: The requested address '/admin/accounts/add' was not found on this server." every time the new user add form is submitted.
My code is :

```
public $components = array(
        'Security' => array(
            'csrfExpires' => '+1 hour'
            ),
        'Search.Prg' => array(
            'commonProcess' => array(
                'paramType' => 'named',
                'filterEmpty' => true
            ))


        );

public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_blackHole';
    }

public function _blackHole($error) {
        die($error);
    }
```

By doing so, 'auth' error has appeared.

This is my view code.

```
<div class="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>アカウント登録</h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                <br />
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('MasterUser', array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-label-left', 'inputDefaults' => array('label' => false, 'div' => false), 'id' => 'demo-form', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('last_name', '姓 <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('first_name', '名 <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('last_name_kana', 'セイ <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('last_name_kana', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('first_name_kana', ' メイ <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('first_name_kana', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('username', ' ログイン ID <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('mail', ' メールアドレス <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('mail', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('password', ' パスワード <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('password_confirm', ' 確認用パスワード <span class="required">*</span>', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->label('', '', array('class' => 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'));?>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->radio('role',array('1'=>'管理者','2'=>'編集者'), array('default' => '1', 'class' => 'flat', 'legend' => false, 'label' => false)); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </p>

                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->button('戻る', array('type' => 'reset', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->button('削除', array('type' => 'reset', 'class' => 'btn btn-default')); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->button('変更を保存', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I do?
Please help me.I have googled but it was just the waste of time.I have no way to do.
Please help me.

Comment: What does your form template look like? Are you altering the form before submitting it?

Answer (score 0):

The security component will blackhole your requests if you are trying to send form data without keeping in the hidden token fields that the Form Component generates.

This happens a lot if you are sending AJAX requests, the best way to get around this would be to simply Serialize the form that you create with the Cake Form Component and send that rather than trying to send discrete values directly through AJAX:

```
$.post('/controller/action', $('#my-form-id').serialize(), function(data) {
            result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(!result) {
                //do Something
            } else {
                //succeeded
}
```

If you inspect the data that gets sent to your Controller action through this then you will see the extra fields that will prevent Cake Security Component from blackholing your request!

If you are not using AJAX then simply ensure you build your forms with the Form Helper - also note that if you alter the forms after they have been generated then CakePHP will blackhole your request because it detects that the form has been tampered with - this is for your security.

If you are getting an Auth error showing in your blackhole request then I would check that the actions you are accessing have $this->Auth->allow() in them (or you are logged in!), try putting in $this->Auth->allow() into your beforeFilter to check this is the cause (this disabled Auth for that controller) - if so then you need to look at your Authorisation system.

Please check out the following links:

[CakePHP Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html)

[CakePHP Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

[Restricting HTTP Methods allowed](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#restricting-http-methods)

[Making Actions Public - Disabling Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)

Comment: Thank you so much, Voycey. How should I do this without Ajax?

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully make things a bit clearer, basically if you arent using AJAX you must be messing with the form after it is rendered somehow (or have enabled the Security Component but not used the Form Helper to build your form) so the Security Component is trying to protect you - please update your original question with the view code you are trying to use with this

Comment: Yes, Vocey. I have edited my original question for my view code.Please guide me.

Comment: Can you also post the full errors you are getting please as you mention an Auth Error?

Comment: Auth error appears because of public function _blackHole($error) {
        die($error);
    }. Without die($error), "The request has been black-holed. Error: The requested address '/admin/accounts/add' was not found on this server." appears instead.

Comment: all _blackHole provides is a callback for when it gets blackholed! What is the Auth Error you get?

Comment: Post the Auth Error that you get! - you dont only get that error because of the callback - the callback just displays it!

Comment: Yes, it's just a word 'auth' appeared on the screen after the request is black-holed.

Comment: I have updated my answer - this is about as much help as I can give you with limited information im afraid

Comment: Nevermind. I feel really thankful to you, Sir Voycey.